# Dropdown menu (with images and UL LI list)

Tags: jquery, css

I have a drop down menu (I fixed the position) and `display: none;` than I just change the display to block. and I have this:

**JavaScript**

```
$('.dropdownmenu').hover(function () {
        console.log("hovered");
    },
    function () {
        console.log("out");
    }
);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdownmenu" style="display: none;">
    <div id="dropdownmenuheader">
        <ul class="dropdownmenulist">
            <li>
                <div class="dbordermenulist"><a href="/blah">Web design & development</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="dbordermenulist"><a href="/blah">Web hosting</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="dbordermenulist"><a href="/blah">Branding</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="dbordermenulist"><a href="/blah">Digital Marketing</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="border-bottom: 0;">
                <div class="dbordermenulist" style="border-bottom: 0;"><a href="/blah">Software Development</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="dropdowngradient"></div>
</div>
```

But mouseenter, mouseleave or hover don't seem to work, I'm trying to create an effect when somebody hovers over it it stays visible but when mouse leaves for 2secs it fades away. (I know that I need to use timers, but I  cant get `.hover` triggered).

Comment: The element is hidden completely (display:none), mouse events won't trigger unless it is visible.

Comment: I'm changing it on mouse over a menu button, and becomes visible.. but nothing is triggered from there on.. the li a hovers work fine (the drop down menu list) but the hover doesn't trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this may not provide an answer to your initial question, i ask my self, why you don't use CSS for this usecase?

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/R9NNx/1/

Updated example with CSS transitions and a delay on hover: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/R9NNx/10/

```
ul.dropdownmenulist {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul.dropdownmenulist > li {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
ul.dropdownmenulist > li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightgray;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 2px 2px 2px;
}

ul.dropdownmenulist > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

With such HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdownmenulist">
    <li><a href="#">What we do</a>

        <ul>
            <li> <a href="/blah">Web design & development</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="/blah">Web hosting</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="/blah">Branding</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="/blah">Digital Marketing</a>

            </li>
            <li>
<a href="/blah">Software Development</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">What we do</a>

        <ul>
            <li> <a href="/blah">Web design & development</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="/blah">Web hosting</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="/blah">Branding</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="/blah">Digital Marketing</a>

            </li>
            <li>
<a href="/blah">Software Development</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Because I want a delay (timer) after mouse leaves and fadeTo(2000,0);

Comment: I was hoping you would say something like that ;) Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/R9NNx/10/